# proper PHP mcrypt encryption methods?

Tags: php, mcrypt

Ok, I have tried to create my own encryption/decryption methods using PHP `mcrypt`, and when I posted them a while back some called them "trash". They were mentioning things about "Initialization Vectors" and such. Basically, how can I make these cryptography methods better:

```
function encrypt($key, $data){
    $encrypted_data = mcrypt_cbc(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_192, $key, $data, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT);
    return base64_encode($encrypted_data);
}

function decrypt($key, $encryptedData){
    $dec = base64_decode($encryptedData);
    $decrypt = mcrypt_cbc(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_192, $key, $dec, MCRYPT_DECRYPT);
    return trim($decrypt);
}
```

I want these to work the best they can except I am a duck in a brand new world when it comes to `mcrypt`, any suggestions are welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a snippet of the mcrypt functions I use.  They use `mcrypt_generic` and `mdecrypt_generic`, which should be used according to the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mcrypt.php).

```
function encrypt($key, $data){
    $b = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $enc = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($enc), MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
    mcrypt_generic_init($enc, md5($key), $iv);

    // PKCS7 Padding from: https://gist.github.com/1077723
    $dataPad = $b-(strlen($data)%$b);
    $data .= str_repeat(chr($dataPad), $dataPad);

    $encrypted_data = mcrypt_generic($enc, $data);

    mcrypt_generic_deinit($enc);
    mcrypt_module_close($enc);

    return array(
        'data' => base64_encode($encrypted_data),
        'iv' => base64_encode($iv)
    );
}

function decrypt($key, $iv, $encryptedData){
    $iv = base64_decode($iv);
    $enc = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');
    mcrypt_generic_init($enc, md5($key), $iv);

    $encryptedData = base64_decode($encryptedData);
    $data = mdecrypt_generic($enc, $encryptedData);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($enc);
    mcrypt_module_close($enc);

    // PKCS7 Padding from: https://gist.github.com/1077723
    $dataPad = ord($data[strlen($data)-1]);

    return substr($data, 0, -$dataPad);
}
```

I don't know much about `mcrypt` either, so I just kinda hacked these together.  I `md5` the key so it's always 32 characters (the max key length), and I randomly calculate an "Initialization Vector".

Using [PKCS7 Padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#Byte_padding) is better because you can have strings that end in white space (as `trim` would remove that), also the encryption is more efficient when the string is a certain length.

I'm using AES 256 (MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256) here, but AES 192 (MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_192) would work too.

Demo: http://ideone.com/WA5Tk

Comment: I'm just wondering if you've heard any feedback about the strength of these functions.  I think they look good, might even use them myself... but this is a bit above me, to be honest...

Comment: I wrote these myself after searching around and finding other (similar) functions.  They seem strong, not sure how strong they are, to be honest.

Comment: So we need to store the IV to decrypt the data?

Comment: @xendi: Yes, the IV is needed in order to decrypt the data.

Comment: Shouldn't we be using something better than md5() to hash the key? Perhapse a better hashing algo with a salt?

Comment: AES256 will only allow a key size of 32? If that is the case we have other 32char options here: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php . I was reading and some have possible attacks. What about using each algo that produces 32 and hash the rusult with the previous result, effectively hashing 7 times?

Comment: Also, I don't understand why you didn't have to base64_decode they key in the decrypt function. Also, I don't understand why we have to base64encode anything at all.

Comment: @xendi: In the encode function, both `mcrypt_generic` and `mcrypt_create_iv` output binary data.  The base64 is only there because of that.  If you want to remove that and store it as binary data, that's fine.

Comment: @hexalys: I'm not really sure.  I don't know much about encryption.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an iv with `mcrypt_create_iv()`, using the appropriate size for your encryption mode.

```
$size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_192, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($size, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);
```

Then pass it to `mcrypt_cbc()` as the optional 5th parameter.  The only changes I've made here to your original functions are to pass in `$iv`:

```
function encrypt($key, $data, $iv){
    $encrypted_data = mcrypt_cbc(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_192, $key, $data, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT, $iv);
    return base64_encode($encrypted_data);
}

function decrypt($key, $encryptedData, $iv){
    $dec = base64_decode($encryptedData);
    $decrypt = mcrypt_cbc(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_192, $key, $dec, MCRYPT_DECRYPT, $iv);
    return trim($decrypt);
}
```

Comment: In the encryption he's using `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_192`, so make sure you use that in `mcrypt_get_iv_size` to make sure the Initialization Vector is the right length.